# Producing a table from a loop with one array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm attempting to create a table using a loop. The number of columns is what matters, it should be 6-7, while the number of rows is irrelevant.

The problem here is that I need to create this from one array only, which has a set of image names which I need to display through the table.

**This is the PHP:**

```
if ($mode == 'skins')
{
    $player_gender  = ($player_data['playerGender'] == true) ? 'male' : 'female';
    $skins_array    = $samp->skin('small', false, $player_gender);
    $index_counter  = 0;

    foreach ($skins_array as $skin_img)
    {
        $template->assign_block_vars('skinrow', array(
            'IMAGE_PATH'    => $root_path . $config['skins_path'] . '/Skin_' . $skin_img . '.png',
        ));
    }
}
```

**And this is the HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <!-- BEGIN skinrow -->
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{skinrow.IMAGE_PATH}"><img src="{skinrow.IMAGE_PATH}" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- END skinrow -->
    </table>
</div>
```

The template engine used in this case is from phpBB.

If I include the `<tr>` in the loop in the HTML, I get my results all going down (vertical) in one column and when I exclude the `<tr>` from the loop, the results all go aside in one row (horizontal).

So, I basically care for the number of columns only, I want those to be limited to 6-7.

I'm failing to see the logic on achieving this. Any help would be appreicated.

**Here is an example array with the data I'm using:** http://pastebin.com/uDMeBJw6

If the template engine is causing you trouble to understand the code, please let me know and I'll try to convert it to a pure PHP example.

Comment: Use a modulo like <?php if ($rowNumber % 6 == 0) print '<tr>' .... and the same if conditional for the closing tr tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY phpBB skills are non-existant, but maybe this will do the trick:

**Template:**

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!-- BEGIN skinrow -->
                {skinrow.NEW_TR} <!-- **EDITED** -->
                <td><a href="{skinrow.IMAGE_PATH}"><img src="{skinrow.IMAGE_PATH}" />                   </a></td>
            <!-- END skinrow -->
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**PHP (loop only):**

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($skins_array as $skin_img)
{
    $new_tr = ($counter && ($counter % 7 === 0)) ? '</tr><tr>' : ''; // **EDITED**
    $template->assign_block_vars('skinrow', array(
        'NEW_TR' => $new_tr, 
        'IMAGE_PATH'    => $root_path . $config['skins_path'] . '/Skin_' . $skin_img . '.png',
    ));
}
```

Code is untested, this is just an idea.
... and it's probably cleaner to do `for` instead of dancing with `foreach` and `$counter` :)

Comment: This is producing the same effect as putting the `<tr>` in the loop again :\

Comment: it shouldn't! The idea is to have `</tr><tr>` only in every 7th (or 6th) block. I'm probably doing something wrong with the template logic (blocks) if it does :(

Comment: Sorry, it worked! It was a mistake from my part. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sure thing! You deserved it as you helped me out. Anyway, how can I make the first `<td>` part of the first row? It looks like this momentarily: http://i.imgur.com/j6esOCU.png

Comment: @Dugi Um, yeah, I was concerned to make the ending of the table ok and so I forgot all about the beginning :) See my edited answer.